# What does this regex (\/?) mean?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-greedy

The following code is taken from Jon Resig's book [Secrets of JavaScript Ninja](http://www.amazon.in/Secrets-JavaScript-Ninja-John-Resig/dp/193398869X)

```
var html = "<div class='test'><b>Hello</b> <i>world!</i></div>";
var results = html.match(/<(\/?)(\w+)([^>]*?)>/);
```

I want to understand the meaning of the first *capture* (within the parenthesis) ie `(\/?)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It matches an optional slash. The slash needs to be escaped because slashes also serve as   delimiters in JavaScript regex literals.

It's not really useful to surround it with capturing parentheses. `\/?` would work as well (unless you later on want to check whether you have matched an opening or a closing tag).

Answer (score 4):

It is either *exactly one* `/` or nothing.  `/` has to be escaped inside regexp because it means "end of regexp" when unescaped.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Yes the answer is correct. I just edited to make it more clear and ofcourse +1.